# Create New Project Android Studio 0.2.3 - Unable to start Gradle daemon process

Tags: android-studio, gradle, daemon, gradle-daemon

I'm having serious problems with Android Studio.
I have totally uninstalled Android Studio, and any copies of Eclipse on my PC.
I then deleted the .gradle .android folders in the users folder.
I then Re-installed the latest release on my PC.
The .gradle and .android folders have been recreated.

I now try to create a new project.
I set all the usual, and then the following error comes up:

[image: gradle error message when trying to create new project.]

I have read multiple posts, most for older versions of Android Studio.
My SDK is up to date, and yes I do have the Android Support Repository Revision 2 installed as well as Android Support Library Rev 18.

Why this has to be so complicated I just cannot understand.

Regards
Adrian Wreyford

Comment: Android Studio is an alpha release, and problems are to be expected. That said, it sounds like you don't have enough free memory. What does the IDE log say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I managed to solve it after many hours of trying.

First of all I use Windows 7, with 16GB ram, and it was the system path that was truncated!
This left me without the proper GRADLE_HOME path.

I manually downloaded the latest Gradle-1.7 build.
Android studio 0.2.3 was using 1.6, but subsequently to my manual fix 0.2.5 uses Gradle-1.7.

I created a System variable: GRADLE_HOME with value: D:\gradle-1.7 that points to my manual Gradle install.

I broke my 'real path' (before windows truncated it) into 'extended' path variables, thus shortening my actual path, and inserted the following at the end of the path:
%GRADLE_HOME%/bin;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;

There are many links on dealing with truncated windows path on stackoverflow.
And that was all that was required to get it working.

Hope I can help someone else!

Answer (score 10):

The only way I made this working was to add this line

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

to `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error but the root cause was my internet security suite. I am using Comodo and I found disabling auto-sandbox solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving my Gradle folder to the root of the drive, as I suspected it was some sort of path problem. This didn't solve it immediately however it worked after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the projects that were showing up on the Android Studio startup. That fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just closed Android Studio, deleted the gradle folder from the Android Studio folder, and reopened the studio. It rebuilt it and now it works perfect.